# how to check permissions on a table in sybase ase

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

how to check permissions on a table in sybase ase 15-2. I wan to check all the existing permissions on a table.

```
I tried exec sp_helprotect 'dbo.mytable'
```

Also How to check `what are all groups are having what are all permissions on a table?`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`sp_helpgroup` will list groups in the current database.

`sp_helpgroup GROUPNAME` will list the groups members.

`sp_helprotect TABLENAME` will list the permission details (must be a table in the current database)

`sp_helprotect USERNAME` will list user's permission details

Please take a look at some the Sybase System Administration Guides 1 & 2.  As a new user to ASE, you will find many of your answers there.

[System Admin Guide 1](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc31654.1550/html/sag1/title.htm)

[System Admin Guide 2](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc31644.1550/html/sag2/title.htm)

[SyBooks Online for ASE](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?docset=/com.sybase.infocenter.help.ase.15.5/title.htm&docSetID=1637)

Answer (score 6):

There is a system table sysprotects where all the user and group permissions are stored. You can join with sysusers to obtain the results.

SP:
sp_helprotect  gives you the required information.